# reading multi-row header from csv data

Tags: pgfplots, header-footer, multirow

I have a csv file that contains signal points that I would like to plot with pgfplots.

My problem is that I formatted the Matlab export in a way so that the units of each signal is written under the header column (I'd like it to stay this way, so I could use this information in my tables). Now when i try to read out the columns to plot my data, I get the error that their unit is in the way of the data being read out.

Is there a way to use a header and still be able to skip a certain row while reading? 
That way i could read out my data and skip the unit row/header while doing so.

The following code is a MWE of how my code looks and the commented out row is basically the mentioned unit row, which I would like to consider in my table. The code works when the unit row is commented out but if one uncomments it then an error occurs.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid = major]
    \addplot[color=blue]
    table[x=t, y=u_C] {
        t   u_C
        %\second   \volt
        0.000000e+00    1.025483e-02
        1.000000e-02    1.067231e-02
        2.000000e-02    1.089647e-02
        3.000000e-02    1.091086e-02
        4.000000e-02    1.070236e-02
        5.000000e-02    1.026160e-02
        6.000000e-02    9.583387e-03
        7.000000e-02    8.667108e-03
        8.000000e-02    7.516976e-03
        9.000000e-02    6.142264e-03
        1.000000e-01    4.557415e-03
        1.100000e-01    2.782068e-03
        1.200000e-01    8.409701e-04
        1.300000e-01    -1.236215e-03
        1.400000e-01    -3.415216e-03
        1.500000e-01    -5.657576e-03
        1.600000e-01    -7.921179e-03
        1.700000e-01    -1.016090e-02
        1.800000e-01    -1.232933e-02
        1.900000e-01    -1.437762e-02
        2.000000e-01    -1.625642e-02
        2.100000e-01    -1.791680e-02
        2.200000e-01    -1.931133e-02
        2.300000e-01    -2.039514e-02
        2.400000e-01    -2.112699e-02
        2.500000e-01    -2.147032e-02
        2.600000e-01    -2.139432e-02
        2.700000e-01    -2.087488e-02
        2.800000e-01    -1.989552e-02
        2.900000e-01    -1.844818e-02
        3.000000e-01    -1.653390e-02
        3.100000e-01    -1.416335e-02
        3.200000e-01    -1.135722e-02
        3.300000e-01    -8.146375e-03
        3.400000e-01    -4.571887e-03
        3.500000e-01    -6.847962e-04
        3.600000e-01    3.454317e-03
        3.700000e-01    7.775987e-03
        3.800000e-01    1.220274e-02
        3.900000e-01    1.665020e-02
        4.000000e-01    2.102837e-02
        4.100000e-01    2.524319e-02
        4.200000e-01    2.919817e-02
        4.300000e-01    3.279623e-02
        4.400000e-01    3.594173e-02
        4.500000e-01    3.854242e-02
        4.600000e-01    4.051163e-02
        4.700000e-01    4.177037e-02
        4.800000e-01    4.224938e-02
        4.900000e-01    4.189119e-02
        5.000000e-01    4.065198e-02
        5.100000e-01    3.850331e-02
        5.200000e-01    3.543363e-02
        5.300000e-01    3.144955e-02
        5.400000e-01    2.657680e-02
        5.500000e-01    2.086087e-02
        5.600000e-01    1.436730e-02
        5.700000e-01    7.181592e-03
        5.800000e-01    -5.913041e-04
        5.900000e-01    -8.827941e-03
        6.000000e-01    -1.738774e-02
        6.100000e-01    -2.611480e-02
        6.200000e-01    -3.484017e-02
        6.300000e-01    -4.338452e-02
        6.400000e-01    -5.156122e-02
        6.500000e-01    -5.917973e-02
        6.600000e-01    -6.604937e-02
        6.700000e-01    -7.198324e-02
        6.800000e-01    -7.680237e-02
        6.900000e-01    -8.033986e-02
        7.000000e-01    -8.244509e-02
        7.100000e-01    -8.298774e-02
        7.200000e-01    -8.186168e-02
        7.300000e-01    -7.898853e-02
        7.400000e-01    -7.432086e-02
        7.500000e-01    -6.784496e-02
        7.600000e-01    -5.958314e-02
        7.700000e-01    -4.959542e-02
        7.800000e-01    -3.798063e-02
        7.900000e-01    -2.487687e-02
        8.000000e-01    -1.046119e-02
        8.100000e-01    5.051456e-03
        8.200000e-01    2.141012e-02
        8.300000e-01    3.833062e-02
        8.400000e-01    5.549924e-02
        8.500000e-01    7.257739e-02
        8.600000e-01    8.920707e-02
        8.700000e-01    1.050173e-01
        8.800000e-01    1.196315e-01
        8.900000e-01    1.326747e-01
        9.000000e-01    1.437825e-01
        9.100000e-01    1.526090e-01
        9.200000e-01    1.588353e-01
        9.300000e-01    1.621779e-01
        9.400000e-01    1.623962e-01
        9.500000e-01    1.592993e-01
        9.600000e-01    1.527531e-01
        9.700000e-01    1.426847e-01
        9.800000e-01    1.290879e-01
        9.900000e-01    1.120265e-01
        1.000000e+00    9.163694e-02
        1.010000e+00    6.813077e-02
        1.020000e+00    4.179524e-02
        1.030000e+00    1.299338e-02
        1.040000e+00    -1.783751e-02
        1.050000e+00    -5.018880e-02
        1.060000e+00    -8.348550e-02
        1.070000e+00    -1.170934e-01
        1.080000e+00    -1.503285e-01
        1.090000e+00    -1.824696e-01
        1.100000e+00    -2.127725e-01
        1.110000e+00    -2.404867e-01
        1.120000e+00    -2.648741e-01
        1.130000e+00    -2.852271e-01
        1.140000e+00    -3.008880e-01
        1.150000e+00    -3.112656e-01
        1.160000e+00    -3.158511e-01
        1.170000e+00    -3.142304e-01
        1.180000e+00    -3.060947e-01
        1.190000e+00    -2.912475e-01
        1.200000e+00    -2.696106e-01
        1.210000e+00    -2.412282e-01
        1.220000e+00    -2.062711e-01
        1.230000e+00    -1.650406e-01
        1.240000e+00    -1.179738e-01
        1.250000e+00    -6.564866e-02
        1.260000e+00    -8.790385e-03
        1.270000e+00    5.172491e-02
        1.280000e+00    1.148688e-01
        1.290000e+00    1.794650e-01
        1.300000e+00    2.442021e-01
        1.310000e+00    3.076558e-01
        1.320000e+00    3.683229e-01
        1.330000e+00    4.246655e-01
        1.340000e+00    4.751626e-01
        1.350000e+00    5.183658e-01
        1.360000e+00    5.529519e-01
        1.370000e+00    5.777679e-01
        1.380000e+00    5.918634e-01
        1.390000e+00    5.945073e-01
        1.400000e+00    5.851913e-01
        1.410000e+00    5.636205e-01
        1.420000e+00    5.296980e-01
        1.430000e+00    4.835085e-01
        1.440000e+00    4.253058e-01
        1.450000e+00    3.555115e-01
        1.460000e+00    2.747259e-01
        1.470000e+00    1.837547e-01
        1.480000e+00    8.365076e-02
        1.490000e+00    -2.423406e-02
        1.500000e+00    -1.381940e-01
        1.510000e+00    -2.561251e-01
        1.520000e+00    -3.755095e-01
        1.530000e+00    -4.934455e-01
        1.540000e+00    -6.067399e-01
        1.550000e+00    -7.120641e-01
        1.560000e+00    -8.061604e-01
        1.570000e+00    -8.860643e-01
        1.580000e+00    -9.493014e-01
        1.590000e+00    -9.940179e-01
        1.600000e+00    -1.019022e+00
        1.610000e+00    -1.023740e+00
        1.620000e+00    -1.008102e+00
        1.630000e+00    -9.724051e-01
        1.640000e+00    -9.171655e-01
        1.650000e+00    -8.430038e-01
        1.660000e+00    -7.505677e-01
        1.670000e+00    -6.405062e-01
        1.680000e+00    -5.134983e-01
        1.690000e+00    -3.703422e-01
        1.700000e+00    -2.121083e-01
        1.710000e+00    -4.035356e-02
        1.720000e+00    1.426172e-01
        1.730000e+00    3.334854e-01
        1.740000e+00    5.277265e-01
        1.750000e+00    7.196021e-01
        1.760000e+00    9.024443e-01
        1.770000e+00    1.069265e+00
        1.780000e+00    1.213589e+00
        1.790000e+00    1.330281e+00
        1.800000e+00    1.416088e+00
        1.810000e+00    1.469754e+00
        1.820000e+00    1.491717e+00
        1.830000e+00    1.483568e+00
        1.840000e+00    1.447475e+00
        1.850000e+00    1.385694e+00
        1.860000e+00    1.300245e+00
        1.870000e+00    1.192731e+00
        1.880000e+00    1.064286e+00
        1.890000e+00    9.156060e-01
        1.900000e+00    7.470667e-01
        1.910000e+00    5.589184e-01
        1.920000e+00    3.515877e-01
        1.930000e+00    1.261093e-01
        1.940000e+00    -1.153016e-01
        1.950000e+00    -3.685953e-01
        1.960000e+00    -6.273254e-01
        1.970000e+00    -8.824969e-01
        1.980000e+00    -1.123181e+00
        1.990000e+00    -1.338023e+00
        2.000000e+00    -1.517274e+00
        2.010000e+00    -1.654537e+00
        2.020000e+00    -1.747479e+00
        2.030000e+00    -1.797346e+00
        2.040000e+00    -1.807731e+00
        2.050000e+00    -1.783221e+00
        2.060000e+00    -1.728359e+00
        2.070000e+00    -1.647035e+00
        2.080000e+00    -1.542229e+00
        2.090000e+00    -1.415980e+00
        2.100000e+00    -1.269471e+00
        2.110000e+00    -1.103171e+00
        2.120000e+00    -9.170172e-01
        2.130000e+00    -7.106536e-01
        2.140000e+00    -4.837670e-01
        2.150000e+00    -2.365829e-01
        2.160000e+00    2.943436e-02
        2.170000e+00    3.106929e-01
        2.180000e+00    6.005813e-01
        2.190000e+00    8.890009e-01
        2.200000e+00    1.162913e+00
        2.210000e+00    1.408253e+00
        2.220000e+00    1.612789e+00
        2.230000e+00    1.768695e+00
        2.240000e+00    1.873586e+00
        2.250000e+00    1.929755e+00
        2.260000e+00    1.942350e+00
        2.270000e+00    1.917496e+00
        2.280000e+00    1.860981e+00
        2.290000e+00    1.777570e+00
        2.300000e+00    1.670801e+00
        2.310000e+00    1.543033e+00
        2.320000e+00    1.395598e+00
        2.330000e+00    1.228988e+00
        2.340000e+00    1.043056e+00
        2.350000e+00    8.372413e-01
        2.360000e+00    6.108658e-01
        2.370000e+00    3.635781e-01
        2.380000e+00    9.600333e-02
        2.390000e+00    -1.893635e-01
        2.400000e+00    -4.871260e-01
        2.410000e+00    -7.881778e-01
        2.420000e+00    -1.079752e+00
        2.430000e+00    -1.346937e+00
        2.440000e+00    -1.575578e+00
        2.450000e+00    -1.755467e+00
        2.460000e+00    -1.882200e+00
        2.470000e+00    -1.956944e+00
        2.480000e+00    -1.984641e+00
        2.490000e+00    -1.971835e+00
        2.500000e+00    -1.925000e+00
        2.510000e+00    -1.849624e+00
        2.520000e+00    -1.749874e+00
        2.530000e+00    -1.628616e+00
        2.540000e+00    -1.487569e+00
        2.550000e+00    -1.327511e+00
        2.560000e+00    -1.148479e+00
        2.570000e+00    -9.499833e-01
        2.580000e+00    -7.312638e-01
        2.590000e+00    -4.916579e-01
        2.600000e+00    -2.311485e-01
        2.610000e+00    4.884032e-02
        2.620000e+00    3.444258e-01
        2.630000e+00    6.482549e-01
        2.640000e+00    9.490364e-01
        2.650000e+00    1.232329e+00
        2.660000e+00    1.482936e+00
        2.670000e+00    1.688257e+00
        2.680000e+00    1.841019e+00
        2.690000e+00    1.940025e+00
        2.700000e+00    1.988898e+00
        2.710000e+00    1.993866e+00
        2.720000e+00    1.961742e+00
        2.730000e+00    1.898646e+00
        2.740000e+00    1.809434e+00
        2.750000e+00    1.697596e+00
        2.760000e+00    1.565372e+00
        2.770000e+00    1.413958e+00
        2.780000e+00    1.243704e+00
        2.790000e+00    1.054326e+00
        2.800000e+00    8.451350e-01
        2.810000e+00    6.153404e-01
        2.820000e+00    3.644985e-01
        2.830000e+00    9.318505e-02
        2.840000e+00    -1.960803e-01
        2.850000e+00    -4.977636e-01
        2.860000e+00    -8.024866e-01
        2.870000e+00    -1.097108e+00
        2.880000e+00    -1.366342e+00
        2.890000e+00    -1.595823e+00
        2.900000e+00    -1.775378e+00
        2.910000e+00    -1.900868e+00
        2.920000e+00    -1.973827e+00
        2.930000e+00    -1.999532e+00
        2.940000e+00    -1.984764e+00
        2.950000e+00    -1.936126e+00
        2.960000e+00    -1.859153e+00
        2.970000e+00    -1.758015e+00
        2.980000e+00    -1.635551e+00
        2.990000e+00    -1.493447e+00
        3.000000e+00    -1.332442e+00
        3.010000e+00    -1.152537e+00
        3.020000e+00    -9.532081e-01
        3.030000e+00    -7.336619e-01
        3.040000e+00    -4.932068e-01
        3.050000e+00    -2.318026e-01
        3.060000e+00    4.913790e-02
        3.070000e+00    3.457213e-01
        3.080000e+00    6.505531e-01
        3.090000e+00    9.522661e-01
        3.100000e+00    1.236322e+00
        3.110000e+00    1.487440e+00
        3.120000e+00    1.692983e+00
        3.130000e+00    1.845699e+00
        3.140000e+00    1.944464e+00
        3.150000e+00    1.992985e+00
        3.160000e+00    1.997560e+00
        3.170000e+00    1.965052e+00
        3.180000e+00    1.901603e+00
        3.190000e+00    1.812082e+00
        3.200000e+00    1.699977e+00
        3.210000e+00    1.567525e+00
        3.220000e+00    1.415914e+00
        3.230000e+00    1.245487e+00
        3.240000e+00    1.055953e+00
        3.250000e+00    8.466158e-01
        3.260000e+00    6.166747e-01
        3.270000e+00    3.656774e-01
        3.280000e+00    9.419001e-02
        3.290000e+00    -1.952767e-01
        3.300000e+00    -4.971942e-01
        3.310000e+00    -8.021825e-01
        3.320000e+00    -1.097088e+00
        3.330000e+00    -1.366603e+00
        3.340000e+00    -1.596335e+00
        3.350000e+00    -1.776091e+00
        3.360000e+00    -1.901725e+00
        3.370000e+00    -1.974775e+00
        3.380000e+00    -2.000531e+00
        3.390000e+00    -1.985786e+00
        3.400000e+00    -1.937157e+00
        3.410000e+00    -1.860187e+00
        3.420000e+00    -1.759051e+00
        3.430000e+00    -1.636592e+00
        3.440000e+00    -1.494497e+00
        3.450000e+00    -1.333509e+00
        3.460000e+00    -1.153627e+00
        3.470000e+00    -9.543259e-01
        3.480000e+00    -7.348122e-01
        3.490000e+00    -4.943901e-01
        3.500000e+00    -2.330135e-01
        3.510000e+00    4.791367e-02
        3.520000e+00    3.445106e-01
        3.530000e+00    6.493964e-01
        3.540000e+00    9.512155e-01
        3.550000e+00    1.235432e+00
        3.560000e+00    1.486757e+00
        3.570000e+00    1.692530e+00
        3.580000e+00    1.845476e+00
        3.590000e+00    1.944452e+00
        3.600000e+00    1.993152e+00
        3.610000e+00    1.997875e+00
        3.620000e+00    1.965485e+00
        3.630000e+00    1.902135e+00
        3.640000e+00    1.812696e+00
        3.650000e+00    1.700664e+00
        3.660000e+00    1.568281e+00
        3.670000e+00    1.416738e+00
        3.680000e+00    1.246380e+00
        3.690000e+00    1.056920e+00
        3.700000e+00    8.476591e-01
        3.710000e+00    6.177980e-01
        3.720000e+00    3.668806e-01
        3.730000e+00    9.546592e-02
        3.740000e+00    -1.939464e-01
        3.750000e+00    -4.958433e-01
        3.760000e+00    -8.008621e-01
        3.770000e+00    -1.095862e+00
        3.780000e+00    -1.365538e+00
        3.790000e+00    -1.595484e+00
        3.800000e+00    -1.775482e+00
        3.810000e+00    -1.901358e+00
        3.820000e+00    -1.974631e+00
        3.830000e+00    -2.000580e+00
        3.840000e+00    -1.985996e+00
        3.850000e+00    -1.937500e+00
        3.860000e+00    -1.860642e+00
        3.870000e+00    -1.759603e+00
        3.880000e+00    -1.637231e+00
        3.890000e+00    -1.495220e+00
        3.900000e+00    -1.334313e+00
        3.910000e+00    -1.154514e+00
        3.920000e+00    -9.553006e-01
        3.930000e+00    -7.358777e-01
        3.940000e+00    -4.955485e-01
        3.950000e+00    -2.342622e-01
        3.960000e+00    4.658621e-02
        3.970000e+00    3.431296e-01
        3.980000e+00    6.480050e-01
        3.990000e+00    9.498738e-01
        4.000000e+00    1.234211e+00
        4.010000e+00    1.348035e+00
        4.020000e+00    1.434001e+00
        4.030000e+00    1.763964e+00
        4.040000e+00    2.271569e+00
        4.050000e+00    2.828784e+00
        4.060000e+00    3.295038e+00
        4.070000e+00    3.589773e+00
        4.080000e+00    3.706446e+00
        4.090000e+00    3.669744e+00
        4.100000e+00    3.500182e+00
        4.110000e+00    3.204318e+00
        4.120000e+00    2.774834e+00
        4.130000e+00    2.189913e+00
        4.140000e+00    1.410468e+00
        4.150000e+00    3.846573e-01
        4.160000e+00    -9.007856e-01
        4.170000e+00    -2.274652e+00
        4.180000e+00    -3.356009e+00
        4.190000e+00    -3.915062e+00
        4.200000e+00    -4.055733e+00
        4.210000e+00    -3.953885e+00
        4.220000e+00    -3.701269e+00
        4.230000e+00    -3.330308e+00
        4.240000e+00    -2.845787e+00
        4.250000e+00    -2.237786e+00
        4.260000e+00    -1.486267e+00
        4.270000e+00    -5.692806e-01
        4.280000e+00    5.045736e-01
        4.290000e+00    1.624227e+00
        4.300000e+00    2.552139e+00
        4.310000e+00    3.086544e+00
        4.320000e+00    3.219008e+00
        4.330000e+00    3.053501e+00
        4.340000e+00    2.672575e+00
        4.350000e+00    2.107294e+00
        4.360000e+00    1.350842e+00
        4.370000e+00    3.790633e-01
        4.380000e+00    -7.981544e-01
        4.390000e+00    -2.029018e+00
        4.400000e+00    -3.006532e+00
        4.410000e+00    -3.524682e+00
        4.420000e+00    -3.636264e+00
        4.430000e+00    -3.482441e+00
        4.440000e+00    -3.149646e+00
        4.450000e+00    -2.668403e+00
        4.460000e+00    -2.036189e+00
        4.470000e+00    -1.230479e+00
        4.480000e+00    -2.255167e-01
        4.490000e+00    9.535994e-01
        4.500000e+00    2.132755e+00
        4.510000e+00    3.017959e+00
        4.520000e+00    3.448993e+00
        4.530000e+00    3.497503e+00
        4.540000e+00    3.292573e+00
        4.550000e+00    2.907995e+00
        4.560000e+00    2.366183e+00
        4.570000e+00    1.657937e+00
        4.580000e+00    7.569600e-01
        4.590000e+00    -3.484448e-01
        4.600000e+00    -1.570178e+00
        4.610000e+00    -2.648944e+00
        4.620000e+00    -3.319205e+00
        4.630000e+00    -3.547413e+00
        4.640000e+00    -3.461646e+00
        4.650000e+00    -3.168924e+00
        4.660000e+00    -2.715322e+00
        4.670000e+00    -2.106377e+00
        4.680000e+00    -1.323201e+00
        4.690000e+00    -3.390657e-01
        4.700000e+00    8.311525e-01
        4.710000e+00    2.031066e+00
        4.720000e+00    2.965559e+00
        4.730000e+00    3.447580e+00
        4.740000e+00    3.532370e+00
        4.750000e+00    3.353211e+00
        4.760000e+00    2.991133e+00
        4.770000e+00    2.473286e+00
        4.780000e+00    1.793698e+00
        4.790000e+00    9.273228e-01
        4.800000e+00    -1.442914e-01
        4.810000e+00    -1.358326e+00
        4.820000e+00    -2.482322e+00
        4.830000e+00    -3.231321e+00
        4.840000e+00    -3.527202e+00
        4.850000e+00    -3.485136e+00
        4.860000e+00    -3.221974e+00
        4.870000e+00    -2.792955e+00
        4.880000e+00    -2.209052e+00
        4.890000e+00    -1.454516e+00
        4.900000e+00    -5.019904e-01
        4.910000e+00    6.456663e-01
        4.920000e+00    1.859204e+00
        4.930000e+00    2.852672e+00
        4.940000e+00    3.405278e+00
        4.950000e+00    3.541631e+00
        4.960000e+00    3.396051e+00
        4.970000e+00    3.059423e+00
        4.980000e+00    2.565621e+00
        4.990000e+00    1.912765e+00
        5.000000e+00    1.077766e+00
        5.010000e+00    3.784220e-02
        5.020000e+00    -1.164393e+00
        5.030000e+00    -2.323473e+00
        5.040000e+00    -3.143898e+00
        5.050000e+00    -3.506084e+00
        5.060000e+00    -3.508033e+00
        5.070000e+00    -3.274540e+00
        5.080000e+00    -2.869958e+00
        5.090000e+00    -2.310816e+00
        5.100000e+00    -1.584724e+00
        5.110000e+00    -6.645659e-01
        5.120000e+00    4.566032e-01
        5.130000e+00    1.676110e+00
        5.140000e+00    2.723861e+00
        5.150000e+00    3.349681e+00
        5.160000e+00    3.542344e+00
        5.170000e+00    3.433122e+00
        5.180000e+00    3.122960e+00
        5.190000e+00    2.653175e+00
        5.200000e+00    2.026363e+00
        5.210000e+00    1.221851e+00
        5.220000e+00    2.141115e-01
        5.230000e+00    -9.713906e-01
        5.240000e+00    -2.157449e+00
        5.250000e+00    -3.045837e+00
        5.260000e+00    -3.476830e+00
        5.270000e+00    -3.525735e+00
        5.280000e+00    -3.323320e+00
        5.290000e+00    -2.943500e+00
        5.300000e+00    -2.408798e+00
        5.310000e+00    -1.710472e+00
        5.320000e+00    -8.223975e-01
        5.330000e+00    2.699002e-01
        5.340000e+00    1.488282e+00
        5.350000e+00    2.583690e+00
        5.360000e+00    3.282898e+00
        5.370000e+00    3.535605e+00
        5.380000e+00    3.465282e+00
        5.390000e+00    3.182571e+00
        5.400000e+00    2.736846e+00
        5.410000e+00    2.135537e+00
        5.420000e+00    1.360770e+00
        5.430000e+00    3.855645e-01
        5.440000e+00    -7.788964e-01
        5.450000e+00    -1.983925e+00
        5.460000e+00    -2.936087e+00
        5.470000e+00    -3.438214e+00
        5.480000e+00    -3.537460e+00
        5.490000e+00    -3.367881e+00
        5.500000e+00    -3.013328e+00
        5.510000e+00    -2.502830e+00
        5.520000e+00    -1.831587e+00
        5.530000e+00    -9.750852e-01
        5.540000e+00    8.666656e-02
        5.550000e+00    1.297495e+00
        5.560000e+00    2.433204e+00
        5.570000e+00    3.204754e+00
        5.580000e+00    3.521017e+00
        5.590000e+00    3.492357e+00
        5.600000e+00    3.238257e+00
        5.610000e+00    2.816744e+00
        5.620000e+00    2.240476e+00
        5.630000e+00    1.494711e+00
        5.640000e+00    5.520805e-01
        5.650000e+00    -5.878067e-01
        5.660000e+00    -1.803984e+00
        5.670000e+00    -2.814703e+00
        5.680000e+00    -3.389588e+00
        5.690000e+00    -3.542739e+00
        5.700000e+00    -3.408019e+00
        5.710000e+00    -3.079399e+00
        5.720000e+00    -2.592964e+00
        5.730000e+00    -1.948166e+00
        5.740000e+00    -1.122611e+00
        5.750000e+00    -9.252112e-02
        5.760000e+00    1.105071e+00
        5.770000e+00    2.273287e+00
        5.780000e+00    3.114972e+00
        5.790000e+00    3.498017e+00
        5.800000e+00    3.514045e+00
        5.810000e+00    3.289926e+00
        5.820000e+00    2.892901e+00
        5.830000e+00    2.341289e+00
        5.840000e+00    1.623790e+00
        5.850000e+00    7.135182e-01
        5.860000e+00    -3.990118e-01
        5.870000e+00    -1.618901e+00
        5.880000e+00    -2.682019e+00
        5.890000e+00    -3.330393e+00
        5.900000e+00    -3.541089e+00
        5.910000e+00    -3.443522e+00
        5.920000e+00    -3.141670e+00
        5.930000e+00    -2.679259e+00
        5.940000e+00    -2.060326e+00
        5.950000e+00    -1.265021e+00
        5.960000e+00    -2.672433e-01
        5.970000e+00    9.122234e-01
        5.980000e+00    2.104949e+00
        5.990000e+00    3.013402e+00
        6.000000e+00    3.466006e+00

      };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome! Please strip off everything that is specific to your machine like `\input{../definitions.tex}` so that others can compile your example.

Comment: `pgfplots` doesn't support mulitline headers as far as I know. But you can use the technique here: [Multi line header for pgfplotstable](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/74579)

Comment: i hope this post is now a tad better @Schrödinger'scat

Comment: I vote to reopen. Yet I still do not see the need for so many data points. Wouldn't it suffice to have much less.